# Trouble establishing pipe communication between python and cpp

Tags: python, c++, pipe, cross-platform

The first attached piece of code is the python code I was using (in "test.py"). The second one is the c++ code (in "test.cpp" which I compiled to "test.out"). I am using ubuntu (18.04) wsl to run these programs.

I firstly established the pipes that will allow intercommunication between the two processes. Using fork I created a child process to call "test.out", which is the executable of the c++ code. I pass the file descriptors as arguments to the called program.

```
#Python

import os
import subprocess
import time
#establishing communication pipes
r_sub, w_py = os.pipe()
r_py, w_sub = os.pipe()
#creating a subprocess to run c++ code
pid = os.fork()

if pid > 0:
#Parent
    os.close(r_sub)
    os.close(w_sub)

    print("[Py]Parent process is writing : r_py" + str(r_py) + " w_py" + str(w_py) +  "r_sub" + str(r_sub) + " w_sub" + str(w_sub))
    text = b"message"
    #Writing message to c++ .exe
    os.write(w_py,text)
    print("[Py]Written text:", text.decode())

    os.close(w_py)
    #Reading c++ message
    rec = os.fdopen(r_py)
    print("[Py]Received Message " + rec.read())
else:
    #Child
    print("[SubP]Calling c++ .exe : r_sub" + str(r_sub) + " w_sub" + str(w_sub) + " r_py" + str(r_py) + " w_py" + str(w_py))
    #Calling .exe of c++ code
    subprocess.call(["./test.out",str(r_sub),str(w_sub),str(r_py),str(w_py)])
```

```
//c++

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#define MSGSIZE 16

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc < 5){
        printf("[c++]File descriptors are not present");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("[c++]I received file descriptors: r_sub%s w_sub%s r_py%s w_py%s\n",argv[1],argv[2],argv[3],argv[4]);
    //Arguments are received as character arrays -> turning them to integers to use them as file descriptors
    int r_sub = std::stoi(argv[1]), w_sub = std::stoi(argv[2]), r_py = std::stoi(argv[3]), w_py = std::stoi(argv[4]);
    char buffer[MSGSIZE] = "";

    close(r_py);
    close(w_py);
    //Here I find out that read fails
    if(read(r_sub,buffer,MSGSIZE) == -1)
        printf("\n:(\n");

    printf("[c++]Received message: %s\n",buffer);

    //Attempting to send message back to python
    close(r_sub);
    write(w_sub,"message back",MSGSIZE);
    std::cout << "[c++]Finish\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

There are neither compilation errors nor "bad file descriptor" errors, but the communication does not work. Actually no information is received in either end.
The Results:

---

> python3 test.py

[Py]Parent process is writing : r_py5 w_py4r_sub3 w_sub6

[Py]Written text: message

[SubP]Calling c++ .exe : r_sub3 w_sub6 r_py5 w_py4

[c++]I received file descriptors: r_sub3 w_sub6 r_py5 w_py4

:(

[c++]Received message:

[c++]Finish

[Py]Received Message:

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems in your C++ program (like *undefined behavior* because you read your string literal out of bounds in `write(w_sub, "message back", MSGSIZE);`) but the first problem is that your file descriptors aren't inherited by the started program - so they are all bad file descriptors in the C++ program. Always check - don't take anything for granted.

You can set the inheritance mode explicitly in python:

```
os.set_inheritable(r_sub, True) # do this for all fds that should be inherited
```

... or open the pipes with `os.pipe2(0)` which makes them inheritable by default.

And make sure they aren't all closed when you start the sub-process:

```
subprocess.call(["./test.out",str(r_sub),str(w_sub),str(r_py),str(w_py)], close_fds=False)
#                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

For any who are wondering what the corrected version is:

I set the file descriptors inheritable, and when I passed them to the sub-process, I made sure that they were not closing (as per @Ted Lyngmo mentioned). In c++ I set the write length as the message's length to avoid reading out of bounds.

```
#Python

import os
import subprocess
import time
#establishing communication pipes
r_sub, w_py = os.pipe()
r_py, w_sub = os.pipe()
#creating a subprocess to run c++ code
pid = os.fork()
os.set_inheritable(r_sub, True)
os.set_inheritable(w_sub, True)
os.set_inheritable(r_py, True)
os.set_inheritable(w_py, True)

if pid > 0:
#Parent
    os.close(r_sub)
    os.close(w_sub)

    print("[Py]Parent process is writing : r_py" + str(r_py) + " w_py" + str(w_py) +  "r_sub" + str(r_sub) + " w_sub" + str(w_sub))
    text = b"message"
    #Writing message to c++ .exe
    os.write(w_py,text)
    print("[Py]Written text:", text.decode())

    os.close(w_py)
    #Reading c++ message
    rec = os.fdopen(r_py)
    print("[Py]Received Message:" + rec.read())
else:
    #Child
    print("[SubP]Calling c++ .exe : r_sub" + str(r_sub) + " w_sub" + str(w_sub) + " r_py" + str(r_py) + " w_py" + str(w_py))
    #Calling .exe of c++ code
    subprocess.call(["./test.out",str(r_sub),str(w_sub),str(r_py),str(w_py)], close_fds=False)
```

```
//c++

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#define MSGSIZE 16

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc < 5){
        printf("[c++]File descriptors are not present");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("[c++]I received file descriptors: r_sub%s w_sub%s r_py%s w_py%s\n",argv[1],argv[2],argv[3],argv[4]);
    //Arguments are received as character arrays -> turning them to integers to use them as file descriptors
    int r_sub = std::stoi(argv[1]), w_sub = std::stoi(argv[2]), r_py = std::stoi(argv[3]), w_py = std::stoi(argv[4]);
    char buffer[MSGSIZE] = "";
    char buf[] = "message back";

    close(r_py);
    close(w_py);

    //Attempting to receive message
    if(read(r_sub,buffer,MSGSIZE) == -1)
        printf("\n:(\n");

    printf("[c++]Received message: %s\n",buffer);

    //Attempting to send message back to python
    close(r_sub);
    if(write(w_sub,buf,sizeof(buf)) == -1)
        printf("\n:(\n");
    std::cout << "[c++]Finish\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The results come as were initially desired:

---

> python3 test.py

[Py]Parent process is writing : r_py5 w_py4r_sub3 w_sub6

[Py]Written text: message

[SubP]Calling c++ .exe : r_sub3 w_sub6 r_py5 w_py4

[c++]I received file descriptors: r_sub3 w_sub6 r_py5 w_py4

[c++]Received message: message

[c++]Finish

[Py]Received Message:message back

---

Thank you again @Ted Lyngmo for your swift support towards the community!